# Fedora Boot / Out Of Space

Tags: linux, fedora, greyhole

I am using Amahi/Fedora/Greyhole, but I'll try to keep this a general Linux question to save explaining how Greyhole works.

Basically I've ended up with a full boot drive (see /dev/sda3 below). Fedora has ground to a halt. I have no idea what is taking up all the space. I have tried other questions, but have had no luck hunting down caches, tmp dirs etc.

**Potentially relevant Greyhole info:**
The Greyhole NAS service has a landing zone which it monitors and then moves files off to a storage pool (my separate physical drives below). I found the landing zone on my root drive filled up more quickly than it could be cleared (also I had accidentally synced many thousands of tiny files in an iPhoto library). I fixed Greyhole by having the landing zone set up on another drive.

I also cleared out the landing zone on my boot drive. But mysteriously, my boot drive remains full.

I'm new to Linux so please ELI5 any assumptions

df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.5G  8.6M  1.5G   1% /run
tmpfs           1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3        50G   50G   20K 100% /
tmpfs           1.5G   32K  1.5G   1% /tmp
/dev/sdc1       917G   73M  871G   1% /var/hda/files/drives/1tbDisk
/dev/sdd1       459G  328G  108G  76% /var/hda/files/drives/500green
/dev/sdb1       459G  335G  101G  77% /var/hda/files/drives/500blue
/dev/sda1       477M   74M  374M  17% /boot
none            4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /var/spool/greyhole/mem
tmpfs           301M     0  301M   0% /run/user/1000
```

df -i

```
Filesystem       Inodes IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
devtmpfs         382198   458   381740    1% /dev
tmpfs            384173     1   384172    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            384173   514   383659    1% /run
tmpfs            384173    15   384158    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3        100904 96514     4390   96% /
tmpfs            384173    26   384147    1% /tmp
/dev/sdc1      61054976    25 61054951    1% /var/hda/files/drives/1tbDisk
/dev/sdd1      30531584 88745 30442839    1% /var/hda/files/drives/500green
/dev/sdb1      30531584 88244 30443340    1% /var/hda/files/drives/500blue
/dev/sda1        128016   342   127674    1% /boot
none             384173     1   384172    1% /var/spool/greyhole/mem
tmpfs            384173     4   384169    1% /run/user/1000
```

sudo du -hxd1 /

```
17M /etc
100K    /root
1.4G    /var
1.2G    /usr
2.5M    /home
0   /media
0   /mnt
0   /opt
0   /srv
0   /gh
2.6G    /
```

How can I hunt down and fix this capacity issue?

PS if someone could add a Greyhole tag that would be ace.

Comment: Any other directories in your root?  `ls -a /`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were files in the underlying directory that I was mounting my Grehole share to.

**Problem**

Root drive is full, Amahi crashes. SSHing to box and running 'df -h' shows only significant files in /var/hda/files/drives - the mount location of your external data drives.

Even though you are mounting external drives at /var/hda/files/drives over a folder in this location, there could still be files in the underlying file system. In my case from a Greyhole sync when a new external drive wasn't properly mounted. With the data drives mounted it's difficult to tell what's underneath.

**Verify**

- Disable Greyhole
- Add 'nofail' as an argument to fstab for external
  data drives so Fedora doesn't hang on boot without them
- Shut down the
  server and disconnect data drives and reboot
- If there is still data
  accessible in /var/hda/files/drives then you likely have have your
  cause for why your boot is full (you could also simply unmount the
  external drives but I wanted to know for sure)

**Fix**

- Log in to Amahi web UI and create a new (non Greyhole) share e.g. 'temprecovery'
- Move the data out of the boot drive and on to your temp share over SSH e.g. mv /var/hda/files/drives/your_disk/gh /var/hda/files/temprecovery/gh
- On the network, back up your files, then delete them from the share. You can check later if you need them, but it's always best to have a backup.
- On the Amahi web UI: Check out your recovered space under Disk->Partition. Delete the temp share you created.
- Turn off the server, reconnect your drives, turn on it on again, enable Greyhole and profit.
- You will want to edit the 'nofail' argument back out of fstab because if for some reason a data drive doesn't mount at boot in the future, you don't want to risk files being sent to your internal drive again. So it's probably best for the boot to fail if a data drive doesn't come online.

More info in [this post here](https://forums.amahi.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=6538&start=10#p37131).